# Generate summary from robot framework log file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, robotframework

we are using Jenkins for installation which is there from many years in our product.
But now I want to enhance it, we have some basic tests run for each component, each has its own robot log file placed in a folder.
I want a create a batch file using windows cmd to parse all log files in that folder, and get me the test cases which are failed.
Any idea how it can be done?

Thanks

Comment: You can probably use the `FIND` or `FINDSTR` commands. Good Luck.

Comment: For small to medium sized build systems, parsing the files after the fact is probably sufficient and has low development costs, but it won't scale. For most projects that's not a problem, but if you anticipate non-trivial growth in the system, you may need to consider moving some logic to the points of failure, where you can emit specific error logs into an error log directory. Then you don't have to parse through hours or minutes worth of success logs to find the actual failures.

Comment: Thanks squashman and jwdonahue.
How to parse the log file which has say 10 tcs in each log file and get the tcs that are only failed?

Comment: Are you wanting just a list of failed tests? Or do you want take all of the various log files and combine them into a single file?

Comment: Getting a list of failed tests is basic need as of now... but taking all log files and combining them in to a single file is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you requirement is `rebot` option of Robot Framework.

Consider, you have two test suites which are executed separately.

- valid_login.txt
- invalid_login.txt

Each test suite create three log files in Robot framework.

- report.html
- log.html
- output.xml

First thing, you need to create the unique name for these all logs.
This can be done using :

- `-r` for renaming report.html
- `-l` for renaming log.html
- `-o` for renaming output.xml

**Example:**

```
pybot -d "F:\robot framework\WebDemo\Logs" -o "invalid_login.xml" -l "invalid_login.html" -r "invalid_login_report.html" invalid_login.robot
```

In this way, after executing, you will have two set of reports.

Since you want to merge the reports and create the combined report, we will first create only XML log for each test suite.

```
pybot -d "F:\robot framework\WebDemo\Logs" -o "invalid_login.xml" -l None -r None invalid_login.robot
```

Above example will create only XML log file in given directory mentioned with `-d` option.

Once you execute above both test suites, it will create two XML log files.

- invalid_login.xml
- valid_login.xml

Now, you can merge the both XML and create combined report using below command.

```
F:\robot framework\WebDemo>rebot Logs\*.xml
Log:     F:\robot framework\WebDemo\log.html
Report:  F:\robot framework\WebDemo\report.html

F:\robot framework\WebDemo>invalid_login
```

`rebot` will take all XML files in Logs directory and create combined Log and Report file.

[Check this link](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#combining-outputs) for more info !!!

Once you combined the all reports, you can filter the Failed test cases easily in **report.html**

Comment: Thanks Dinesh for detailed Steps :)